# Why is my Moon not orbiting Earth in my physics demo

Tags: c++, physics-engine, raylib

I am in the midst of making a gravitational body demo for my physics engine.  For the demo, I am trying to simulate both all the inner planets' (Mercury-Venus-Earth-Mars) orbits around the sun, as well as the orbit of the moon around the Earth.  The planets are all working as expected, however the Moon does not seem to want to orbit the Earth.  I am at a complete loss for why this is.  I'm pretty sure it's not that the gravity is calculated incorrectly, otherwise the planets would not all correctly orbit the sun.  The calculations to determine the force acting on the moon begin just below the `while(!WindowShouldClose())` loop.  Below is a (rather lengthy) MCVE to see what I mean.  I'm hoping that it is a conceptual issue about how I've set up my initial conditions more than a coding mistake.  Please note that it requires an installation of [raylib](https://www.raylib.com/)

Currently, the moon starts with the correct initial velocity relative to the sun (the combination of the Earth's velocity relative to the Sun and the moon's velocity relative to the Earth), however that velocity never significantly changes, so the moon ends up going in basically a straight line forever.  The "basically" is important.  The Moon *is* being affected by the Earth, just on a much much smaller scale than anticipated

To use the simulation, there are the standard WASD keys, and the mouse to look around.

```
#include "raylib.h"
#include "rlgl.h"
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>

#define real_sqrt sqrt
#define real_pow powf

// Set some physical values for the simulation
#define G 6.67408e-11 // [m^3 kg^-1 s^-2]

#define SOLARMASS 1.989e30 // [kg]
#define SOLARRADIUS 6.957e8 // [m]

#define EARTHMASS 5.97219e24 // [kg]
#define EARTHORBIT 1.496e11 // [m]
#define EARTHVELOCITY 2.978e4 // [m/s] (Relative to Sun)
#define EARTHRADIUS 6.371e6 // [m]

#define MOONMASS 7.34767309e22 // [kg]
#define MOONORBIT 3.844e8 // [m]
#define MOONVELOCITY 1.023e3 // [m/s] (Relative to Earth)
#define MOONRADIUS 1.737e6 // [m]

using namespace std;

namespace engine {
    typedef float real;

    class Vec3 {
        public:
            // Spatial coordinates
            real x;
            real y;
            real z;

        private:
            // Padding to ensure four word alignment
            real pad;

        public:
            // Default constructor creates a 0 vector
            Vec3() : x(0), y(0), z(0) {}

            // Constructor for when values are passed
            Vec3(const real x, const real y, const real z) : x(x), y(y), z(z) {}

        // Get magnitude of vector
        real magnitude() const {
            return real_sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z);
        }

        // Sometimes it is useful and faster to just have the square of the magnitude
        real squareMagnitude() const {
            return x * x + y * y + z * z;
        }

        // Normalize a non-zero vector
        void normalize() {
            real l = magnitude();
            if (l > 0) {
                (*this) *= ((real)1)/l;
            }
        }

        // Multiplies vector by given scalar
        void operator *= (const real scalar) {
            x *= scalar;
            y *= scalar;
            z *= scalar;
        }

        // Returns vector scaled by value
        Vec3 operator * (const real value) const {
            return Vec3(x * value, y * value, z * value);
        }

        // Adds given vector
        Vec3 operator + (const Vec3& v) const {
            return Vec3(x + v.x, y + v.y, z + v.z);
        }

        void operator += (const Vec3& v) {
            x += v.x;
            y += v.y;
            z += v.z;
        }

        // Subtracts given vector
        void operator -= (const Vec3& v) {
            x -= v.x;
            y -= v.y;
            z -= v.z;
        }

        Vec3 operator - (const Vec3& v) const {
            return Vec3(x - v.x, y - v.y, z - v.z);
        }

        // Adds a given scaled vector
        void addScaledVector(const Vec3& v, real scale) {
            x += (v.x * scale);
            y += (v.y * scale);
            z += (v.z * scale);
        }

        real operator * (const Vec3& v) const {
            return x * v.x + y * v.y + z * v.z;
        }

        void operator = (const Vec3& v) {
            x = v.x;
            y = v.y;
            z = v.z;
        }

        void clear() {
            x = y = z = 0;
        }
    }; // class Vec3

    class Particle {
        protected:
            // Keep track of position and its time derivatives
            Vec3 pos;
            Vec3 vel;
            Vec3 acc;

            // Keep track of damping of linear motion
            real damping;

            /**
             * Holds the inverse of the mass of the particle. It
             * is more useful to hold the inverse mass because
             * integration is simpler, and because in real-time
             * simulation it is more useful to have objects with
             * infinite mass (immovable) than zero mass
             * (completely unstable in numerical simulation).
            */
            real inverseMass;

            Vec3 forceAccum;

        public:
            Particle() : pos(0, 0, 0), vel(0, 0, 0), acc(0, 0, 0), damping((real)1.0), inverseMass(0) {};

            Particle(const Vec3 pos, 
                        const Vec3 vel, 
                        const Vec3 acc, 
                        const real damping, 
                        const real inverseMass) : pos(pos), vel(vel), acc(acc), damping(damping), inverseMass(inverseMass) {};

            void integrate(real duration) {
                // We won't integrate particles with infinite or negative mass
                if (inverseMass <= 0.0f) return;

                assert(duration > 0.0);

                // Update linear position.
                pos.addScaledVector(vel, duration);
                pos.addScaledVector(acc, duration * duration * 0.5);

                //Vec3 resultingAcc = acc;
                //resultingAcc.addScaledVector(forceAccum, inverseMass);
                acc = forceAccum * inverseMass;

                // Impose drag.
                vel *= real_pow(damping, duration);

                // Update linear velocity from the acceleration.
                //vel.addScaledVector(resultingAcc, duration);
                vel.addScaledVector(acc, duration);

                // Clear forces
                clearAccumulator();
            } // integrate()

            // Return position of particle
            Vec3 getPosition() const {
                return pos;
            }

            void clearAccumulator() {
                forceAccum.clear();
            }

            void addForce(const Vec3& f) {
                forceAccum += f;
            }

            bool hasFiniteMass() const {
                return inverseMass > 0.0f;
            }

            real getMass() const {
                if (inverseMass == 0) {
                    return std::numeric_limits<float>::max();
                } else {
                    return ((real)1.0)/inverseMass;
                }
            }
    }; // class Particle

    class ParticleForceGenerator {
        public:
            virtual void updateForce(Particle *particle, real duration) = 0;
    };

    class ParticleForceRegistry {
        protected:
            // Keep track of force generator and the particle that called for it
            struct ParticleForceRegistration {
                Particle *particle;
                ParticleForceGenerator *fg;
            };

            // Holds list of registrations
            typedef std::vector<ParticleForceRegistration> Registry;
            Registry registrations;

        public:
            // Registers the given force generator to apply to the given particle
            void add(Particle* particle, ParticleForceGenerator* fg) {
                ParticleForceRegistration registration;
                registration.particle = particle;
                registration.fg = fg;
                registrations.push_back(registration);
            }

            // Clear all registrations from the registry
            void clear() {
                registrations.clear();
            }

            // Calls all the force generators to update the forces of their corresponding particles
            void updateForces(real duration) {
                Registry::iterator i = registrations.begin();

                for (; i != registrations.end(); i++) {
                    i->fg->updateForce(i->particle, duration);
                }
            }
    }; // class ParticleForceRegistry

    class ParticlePointGravity : public ParticleForceGenerator {
        Vec3 origin;
        real mass;

        public:
            ParticlePointGravity(const Vec3& origin, const real mass)
            : origin(origin), mass(mass) 
            {
            }

            void setOrigin(const Vec3& origin) {
                this->origin = origin;
            }

            void updateForce(Particle* particle, real duration) {
                // Check if particle has a finite mass
                if (!particle->hasFiniteMass()) return;

                Vec3 force;

                // Calculate the direction of the force
                Vec3 direction = particle->getPosition() - origin;
                real distance = direction.magnitude();
                direction.normalize();

                // Calculate the magnitude of the force
                real forceMagnitude = -G * particle->getMass() * mass / (distance * distance);
                force = direction * forceMagnitude;
                
                // Apply the force
                particle->addForce(force);
            }
    }; // class ParticlePointGravity
}; // namespace engine

using namespace engine;


int main() {
    // Initial conditions are at the rightmost point of the orbit (looking down on the system), 
    //   where the position is only in x and the velocity is only in z
    Vec3 moon_xi = Vec3(MOONORBIT + EARTHORBIT, 0, 0); // [m]
    Vec3 moon_vi = Vec3(0, 0, MOONVELOCITY + EARTHVELOCITY); // [m/s]
    Vec3 moon_ai = Vec3(0, 0, 0); // [m/s^2]

    Vec3 earth_xi = Vec3(EARTHORBIT, 0, 0); // [m]
    Vec3 earth_vi = Vec3(0, 0, EARTHVELOCITY); // [m/s]
    Vec3 earth_ai = Vec3(0, 0, 0); // [m/s^2]

    Vec3 solGravityOrigin = Vec3(0, 0, 0);
    real solMass = SOLARMASS; // [kg]

    Particle *earth = new Particle(earth_xi, earth_vi, earth_ai, 1, 1/EARTHMASS);
    Particle *moon = new Particle(moon_xi, moon_vi, moon_ai, 1, 1/MOONMASS);

    // Raylib Initialization
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    const int screenWidth = 720;
    const int screenHeight = 450;

    InitWindow(screenWidth, screenHeight, "Djinn - Solar Orbit Demo");

    // Define the camera to look into our 3d world (position, target, up vector)
    Camera camera = { 0 };
    camera.position = (Vector3){ 15.0f, 5.0f, 0.0f };
    camera.target = (Vector3){ 15.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
    camera.up = (Vector3){ 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f };
    camera.fovy = 60.0f;
    camera.projection = CAMERA_PERSPECTIVE;

    SetCameraMode(camera, CAMERA_FIRST_PERSON); // Set a first person camera mode
    SetCameraMoveControls(KEY_W, KEY_S, KEY_D, KEY_A, KEY_SPACE, KEY_LEFT_SHIFT);

    SetTargetFPS(60);                           // Set our game to run at 60 frames-per-second
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    // Time resolution
    real dt = 1e4; // [s]

    // Define force registry
    ParticleForceRegistry registry;

    // Define force generators to be applied to the particle
    ParticlePointGravity* solGravity = new ParticlePointGravity(solGravityOrigin, solMass); // Args: (Vec3) origin, (real) mass
    ParticlePointGravity* earthGravity = new ParticlePointGravity(earth_xi, EARTHMASS);

    // Register force generators with the particle
    registry.add(earth, solGravity);
    registry.add(moon, earthGravity);

    while(!WindowShouldClose()) {
        // Update the forces per loop
        registry.updateForces(dt);

        // Calculate the new pos, vel, and acc of the moon and earth
        earth->integrate(dt);
        moon->integrate(dt);

        // Set the earth gravity's new origin to the new position of the earth
        earthGravity->setOrigin(earth->getPosition());

        // Get positions and scale down to fit on screen
        Vec3 earth_x = earth->getPosition() * 1e-10; // Scale down to tens of meters
        Vec3 moon_x = moon->getPosition() * 1e-10; // Scale down to tens of meters

        // Convert my Vec3 object to a Raylib Vector3 object
        Vector3 *rl_earth_x = reinterpret_cast<Vector3*>(&earth_x); // Raylib vector for drawing
        Vector3 *rl_moon_x = reinterpret_cast<Vector3*>(&moon_x);

        UpdateCamera(&camera);

        BeginDrawing();
            ClearBackground(BLACK);

            BeginMode3D(camera);

                DrawGrid(1000, 1.0f);        // Draw a grid

                DrawSphere(*rl_earth_x, 0.25, BLUE); // Draw earth

                DrawSphere(*rl_moon_x, 0.1, GRAY); // Draw moon
            
                DrawSphere((Vector3){0, 0, 0}, 1, YELLOW); // Draw Sol

            EndMode3D();

            DrawRectangle(10, 30, 150, 75, Fade(SKYBLUE, 0.5f));
            DrawRectangleLines(10, 30, 150, 75, BLUE);

            DrawText("Earth:", 20, 40, 10, WHITE);
            DrawText(TextFormat("X: %02.02f", rl_earth_x->x), 20, 55, 10, WHITE);
            DrawText(TextFormat("Y: %02.02f", rl_earth_x->y), 20, 70, 10, WHITE);
            DrawText(TextFormat("Z: %02.02f", rl_earth_x->z), 20, 85, 10, WHITE);

            DrawText("Moon:", 80, 40, 10, WHITE);
            DrawText(TextFormat("X: %02.02f", rl_moon_x->x), 80, 55, 10, WHITE);
            DrawText(TextFormat("Y: %02.02f", rl_moon_x->y), 80, 70, 10, WHITE);
            DrawText(TextFormat("Z: %02.02f", rl_moon_x->z), 80, 85, 10, WHITE);

            DrawFPS(10, 10);

        EndDrawing();
    }

    CloseWindow();

    return 0;
}
```

NOTE: The flags to compile this code looks like : `-framework IOKit -framework Cocoa -framework OpenGL <backtick>pkg-config --libs --cflags raylib<backtick>`

Comment: I don't know how badly it would affect an Earth/Sun/Moon system, but gravity simulators are notorious for numeric instability - you are adding up numbers of often very different sizes so that order of calculations can matter, and errors accumulate fast, so stepwise accelerating in the direction of the forces isn't going to be stable - at a guess, everything is going to spiral out, at a rate depending on step size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem might be here:

```
registry.add(earth, solGravity);
registry.add(moon, earthGravity);
```

You state that the earth is affected by the sun and the moon is affected by the earth. But you forgot something crucial: The moon is also affected by the sun!

```
registry.add(earth, solGravity);
registry.add(moon, earthGravity);
registry.add(moon, solGravity);
```

In reality, every mass in the universe affects every other mass - no exceptions! So if you want to be completely physically correct, then you also need to have the earth's gravity affect the sun and the moon's gravity affect the earth *and* the sun. The latter is probably far too small to matter for your simulation. But it might matter in case of Jupiter. The influence of Jupiter on the sun is in fact large enough that the Sun and Jupiter orbit a point which is slightly outside of the sun.

And you probably want to simulate fictional solar systems with more extreme orbits and bodies. In those cases your intuition on what matters and what doesn't might be wrong. So which gravity on which body can be ignored and which can not is something I would decide automatically at runtime and not while designing the solar system.

What I would do in this case is put all the bodies into an array (or std::vector) and then just use two nested for-loops to connect every body with every other body, skipping those cases where the body A is so much lighter than body B that it *probably* doesn't matter. The exact cutoff factor would be a tradeoff between accuracy and speed you would need to decide yourself.

Comment: Thanks, you make a great point about the universality of gravity.  I had made too quick of an assumption about the Sun's influence on the moon.  After including that, however, there seems to be another issue that pops up, perhaps unrelated to my initial issue.  The moon now *approximately* orbits the earth for a few seconds (~30) before flying off.  I think this may have to do with the "every mass affects every other mass" functionality that I have yet to implement.  Thanks again!

Comment: @Catyre Yes, it's possible that you have that instability of the moon orbit because you neglected the influence of the moon on Earth. Which [is actually not that small](https://scienceprojectideasforkids.com/barycenter-of-the-earth-moon-system/). But that should be easy to test by adding `registry.add(earth, moonGravity);`